# Using Azure Functions V1 servicebus queue trigger with managed identity in connecting gives Error is Microsoft.ServiceBus: 40400: Endpoint not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8

I am on the latest of VS2019. I created a new azure function project. which scaffolded with below versions of nuget package. No additional changes at all I have made.

[image]

My Function1.cs looks as below

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queue", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

My local.settings.json is as below

[image]

Note: I have to use Managed Identity to listen to the queue. AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_TENANT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET values are all correct. They have granted right permissions on the service bus. If I use V3 of azure function then same setting work well.

When I use V1 version of azure function then when I run the project in VS I get the below error

```
The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.ServiceBus: 40400: Endpoint not found., Resource:sb://xx.servicebus.windows.net/;authentication=managed%20identity;/queue. TrackingId:f4dc24ff-ff67-400d-b09f-94a5a3d9c186_G12, SystemTracker:xx.servicebus.windows.net:;Authentication=Managed%20Identity;/queue, Timestamp:2021-07-14T06:04:06.
```

I tried upgrading Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to the latest available package but then I run into series of dependency issues with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus and other nuget version-related issues.

Kindly help me in getting this barebone structure of the project working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue when I created a project with default packages (****Function V1* with *Service Bus Queue****).

I had fixed with below steps

Created `Function app V1` with `Service Bus Queue trigger`. Updated below marked packages.

Try to add `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` latest version and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` (2.3.0) packages.

[image]

Added the ***Managed Identity Service Bus Queue*** connection string.

[image]

[image]